# Ubuntu & Flavors Installation Errors?

Tags: 14.04, boot, lubuntu, kubuntu

My father owns a rather old (2006ish?) Compaq that had Windows 7 installed on it (x64) and has become so bloated, old, and impaired that it froze up every few seconds and ran slower than a snail. He is a bit strapped for cash and cannot afford a new computer, so I offered to install Ubuntu for him, since I have had good experiences with it in the past when my college laptop's version of Vista broke itself. However, I am unable to get any version of Ubuntu to work, and keep seeing the same error message.

Here's what I've tried so far. When I checked the computer before trying an Ubuntu install, the Windows OS claimed to be 64 bit, so I first tried installing 64 bit versions of Ubuntu (and when that failed) Kubuntu. I first tried via a bootable USB I made following the instructions on the Ubuntu site. The version I tried to install was 14.04.02 LTS. The Ubuntu installation appeared to run and finish installing, but when I restarted the computer and booted it afterwards, it loaded the Ubuntu logo, then gave me this scrambled, gibberish looking glitched image pattern all over the screen and froze. The same thing happened when I tried to install Kubuntu afterwards. I thought perhaps the USB disk was bad, so I tried a few other USBs and different programs to create the bootable disk. The same thing happened each time.

This is the error message I keep getting:

[ 0.125705] pup 00:04 can't evaluate _CRS: 12298

[ 4.857500] ACPI: [Package] has zero elements {f47c4980}

Next, I tried installing from an old CD I bought off ebay a few years back (Ubuntu 11.04 & Kubuntu 11.04) - Oddly enough, Kubuntu 11.04 is able to install and run, but cannot update, install programs, or add any software. Ubuntu hits the same error as the 14.04 version does when I tried the USB stick.

Next, I tried going out and buying DVD-R CD's, and burned my own copies of Ubuntu, Kubuntu, and Lubuntu 14.04, in both x64 and i386, just in the off chance that my dad's old computer lied about being x64. The same thing happens each time I try an install, no matter which flavor I use, or whether i use 64 or 32 bit. When running the install, I get the aforementioned error messages in the terminal, the installation runs, completes, and asks for a reboot, and once I do, it loads just past the Ubuntu/Kubuntu/Lubuntu title screen, then freezes up with some jumbled image that looks like the graphics card had a seizure.

I have no idea what is wrong, and no idea what to do. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Did you ever "try ubuntu" when booting from any of the DVDs? does that work?  (I would start with Lubuntu as that is lowest memory/disk usage and you didn't specify any hardware...)

Answer (score 0):

graphics card seizure hahaha I want to see that :)

Have a look in your bios settings, recently I've encountered  lot of errors regarding EDID and DVI when installing Lubuntu, which are to do with the screen, guess what the problem was? Not the screen or anything to do with graphics drivers- a setting in my BIOS regarding hard drive recognition was wrong. 
So I'd suggest having a look at your bios settings- that has been the stumbling block for failed installations on two of my machines.

I found some more possibly helpful info here;
http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=284419
and here;
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/acpi-error-and-kernel-panic-on-boot-fedora-12-a-780467/

P.S. Try to avoid bios settings which look like they could ruin everything.